# Modeling, Measuring, and Maximizing "Mixedness"

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, optimization, combinations, mathematical-modeling

**Possible key-terms:** combinatorial optimization techniques; simulated annealing; genetic algorithms; Kirkman's schoolgirl problem; Steiner triple systems; orthogonal regrouping.

---

**Background:** My class has $10$ students and $3$ tables; naturally, the students are distributed with $3, 3,$ and $4$ seated at the individual tables. On the second day of class, students sat in the same seats as on day one; I asked them to reseat themselves so that they could sit with new people.

Since there are $4$ students at one table and only $3$ total tables, we know by the pigeonhole principle that at least one pair of students will still be seated together after the reseating. In fact, such a reseating (only one pair of students still seated together) is attainable: the students quickly achieved as much!

**Foreground:** What are the natural notions of mixedness that one uses in similar scenarios for subsequent days? Asking with greater generality, suppose that there are $N$ students with their seats distributed among $k$ tables, each of which contains (on all days) $n_1, \ldots, n_k$ students, respectively, where $\sum n_i = N$.

(In the background case: $N = 10; n_1 = 3, n_2 = 3, n_3 = 4$.)

> **Question:** What sort of literature exists on measuring how mixed up a seating arrangement is (as compared to *all* previous days), and how does one maximize the mixedness moving forward?

If necessary, I am okay with certain assumptions on the $n_i$; surely they should all be positive, and, at least initially, I am okay with them being assumed equal. (Though this will only be possible if $k$ divides $N$, which is not the case in my class!)

References addressing the general problem or solutions for particular cases (e.g., $10$ students at $3$ tables) would all be welcomed.

Comment: Per your request: I think the answer lies in ergodic theory. You can search ArXiv for papers if you think someone has thought of this.

Comment: I gave a fairly practical answer to a similar question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190591/combining-kindergardeners-in-fair-cookie-baking-groups-kirkmans-schoolgirl-p/1190729#1190729

Comment: @Tad Though you refer to them as standard combinatorial optimization techniques, I have no familiarity with simulated annealing or genetic algorithms. A similar post analysis here, if you have the time and energy, would be great! (As far as the number at each table: It would be best if the students who were at the 4-table changed a fair amount, too...)

Answer (score 3):

This definitely sounds like a variation on Kirkman's schoolgirl problem; the original problem had $N = 15$, $n_{1}=\dots=n_{5}=3$, and it was desired that, for seven days in succession, no two girls were "seated at the same table" twice.  For general $N = 3k+3$ (all table sizes $=3$, successive $(1/2)(N-1)$ days), solutions are given by Steiner triple systems admitting a parallelism; similar problems have been looked at for table size 4.

If you are just looking at two days, you can think of having a complete graph on $N$ vertices; now color edges red when kids sit at a table together on the first day, you will get complete graphs of size $n_{1}, \ldots, n_{k}$.  For the second day, you want to embed these subgraphs again, reusing as few edges as possible. I'm guessing you will always be able to obtain the theoretical minimum using a greedy algorithm.

Comment: Just looked up some things, it seems like some similar work has been done under the banner of "Orthogonal Regrouping", specifically in terms of classroom groups and maximizing student interaction.  All references seem to point to equal table sizes, however.  They are either trying to maximize the number of days until you have to repeat a pair of students at a table, or minimize the number of days until every pair of students have worked together.